# Switching from internet explorer to Edge/Chrome

Tags: linux, google-chrome, ssl, internet-explorer, openssl

I'm working on a legacy application, it works with https protocol on internet explorer. when I open the application on microsoft edge or chrome I get the error `NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID`.

On internet explorer, I see the message `Invalid certificate` but the application works.

For now my goal is to make the app work even with http protocol. so I tried to comment the configuration related to SSL certification I found `SSLEngine on` I want to change it to `SSLEngine off` to disable https protocol.
I connected as root, but I get the error `unable to open file for writing: Read-only file system`

How can I fix the problem to make the app work on Edge/Chrome ?

Comment: Are you using Linux? Here's a method that might be able to help you solve the problem, which prevents Edge from automatically switching http protocol to https.
Go to `edge://net-internals/#hsts --> Delete domain security policies --> input a domain name`. Same as Chrome.

Comment: It might be preferable simply to replace the invalid certificate with a trusted, non-expired cert whose CN matches your website domain.